# Cassandra read performance slow on 2000 rows java datastax driver

Tags: java, database, azure, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using apache Cassandra with below configuration and trying to fetch 2000 rows by using [DataStax Java Driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/index.html)   . The number of columns in table is 25 and has 1 partition key and 2 clustering key .

I am running 5 node cluster in azure managed Cassandra  instance and key space has replication factor of 3.

SQL -  **Select * from T1 where c1 = 'x';**  // This query fetches 2000 rows and takes around 110 ms via datastax java driver . select query for single row works faster around 6 ms , but when  select query has to fetch more rows from single partition time increases . How to decrease  read time and bring down read query time around 10-15 ms with 2000 rows select. In my scenario for one partition key c1 , it can have 2000 distinct c2 value . So when I select c1 by query , I want to get all 2000 rows  associated with c1 .

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
     c1 text,
     c2 text,
     c3 int,
     c4 text,
     c5 text,
     c6 int,
     c7 int,
     c8 int,
     c9 int,
     c10 text,
     c11 int,
     c12 int,
     c13 int,
     c14 int,
     c15 int,
     c16 int,
     c17 int,
     c18 int,
     c19 text,
    c20 int,
    c21 int,
    c22 timestamp,
    c23 int,
    c24 int,
    c25 int,
    PRIMARY KEY (c1, c2, c3)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (c2 ASC, c3 ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Example : I am fetching C1 = X all value

```
C1| C2| C3| C3 .....
X | A | M |
X | B | P |
X | C | U |
X | D | I |
```

Comment: Is this method setting any fetch size? Also is the method fetching the 2000 rows running one time and then terminating the JVM? If this is the case try to run the test method multiple times on the same execution and track the time for each method call. Maybe you can post your code so people can check it out easily.

Comment: @SumeetKumarYadav, this is a perfect data modeling in C* item. Couple items in here. What is the exact version of driver being used here (for e.g. `groupID:artifactID:version` format)? Does all your 2000 rows for a given c1 value fall within the recommended total of 5-10MB for efficiency and scale? Have you set any fetch size as Marcos mentioned (or) have you looked at leveraging asynchronous API? -- https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/paging/ & https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/async/ to efficiently fetch huge resultsets?